# How do I declare a two dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

What's the easiest way to create a 2d array. I was hoping to be able to do something similar to this:

```
declare int d[0..m, 0..n]
```

Answer (score 92):

You can also create an associative array, or a "hash-table" like array, by specifying the index of the array.

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'name' => 'John Doe',
        'email' => 'john@example.com'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'name' => 'Jane Doe',
        'email' => 'jane@example.com'
    ),
);
```

Which is equivalent to

```
$array = array();

$array[0] = array();
$array[0]['name'] = 'John Doe';
$array[0]['email'] = 'john@example.com';

$array[1] = array();
$array[1]['name'] = 'Jane Doe';
$array[1]['email'] = 'jane@example.com';
```

Comment: How can we create this same array using looping statements?

Comment: @Anoop-Pete
In the second snippet the two repeating blocks would be placed into the loop and the numeric index replaced by a variable that is incremented each iteration.

Comment: @AnoopPete : for ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){
    print($array[$i]['name']);
}

Answer (score 70):

The following are equivalent and result in a two dimensional array:

```
$array = array(
    array(0, 1, 2),
    array(3, 4, 5),
);
```

or

```
$array = array();

$array[] = array(0, 1, 2);
$array[] = array(3, 4, 5);
```

Comment: Those do not result in two-dimensional arrays, but rather result in an array of arrays.

Comment: @dotancohen That's just semantics, really. Practically the two concepts are the same. The only difference between what is demonstrated there and the kind of multi-dimensional arrays used in languages like C# is syntax. And a fairly small difference in syntax at that.

Comment: In C# at least, the memory requirements are different. An array of arrays allocates only the amount of memory needed for each array. A two-dimensional array allocates the whole N * M of memory.

Comment: @dotancohen The memory requirements between PHP and C# are very different in general, as each language's runtime has it's own way of handling memory. It's generally not something you're concerned with in practice. Not unless you happen to be building some sort of long running, high-performance app, like a game, in which case PHP would be an odd choice of a language.

Answer (score 51):

Just declare? You don't have to. Just make sure variable exists:

```
$d = array();
```

Arrays are resized dynamically, and attempt to write anything to non-exsistant element creates it (and creates entire array if needed)

```
$d[1][2] = 3;
```

This is valid for any number of dimensions without prior declarations.

Comment: Except that tells you nothing about the dimensions. If you're declaring an M x N 2D array, chances are it's a matrix and if it's a matrix chances are you'll be doing multiplication or something on it that will necessitate iterating over the elements, which you can't do if it's "sparse" and don't know the dimensions.

Comment: @cletus: you can just use `count` on the right dimension though, e.g. `count($d[1])`, unless I'm misunderstanding your point?

Comment: Still, PHP does not have multi-dimensional arrays. The possibility will always exit that an array of arrays might be sparse. So, how about making a class that implements a matrix using arrays, at least then you would take more care of proper implementation.

Answer (score 29):

Firstly, PHP doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays, it has arrays of arrays.

Secondly, you can write a function that will do it:

```
function declare($m, $n, $value = 0) {
  return array_fill(0, $m, array_fill(0, $n, $value));
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean "arrays _of_ arrays", instead of "arrays _or_ arrays"?

Comment: Setting up an array of zeroes is a completely pointless exercise. You don't need to declare an array, just use it.

Comment: Except if you need to **iterate** over it or determine it's size like if you're say doing matrix multiplication. There is a perfectly valid case for filling the array values.

Answer (score 14):

For a simple, "fill as you go" kind of solution:

`$foo = array(array());`

This will get you a flexible pseudo two dimensional array that can hold $foo[*n*][*n*] where *n* <= ∞ (of course your limited by the usual constraints of memory size, but you get the idea I hope). This could, in theory, be extended to create as many sub arrays as you need.

Answer (score 11):

Or for larger arrays, all with the same value:

```
$m_by_n_array = array_fill(0, $n, array_fill(0, $m, $value);
```

will create an `$m` by `$n` array with everything set to `$value`.

Answer (score 6):

atli's answer really helped me understand this.  Here is an example of how to iterate through a two-dimensional array.   This sample shows how to find values for known names of an array and also a foreach where you just go through all of the fields you find there.   I hope it helps someone.

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'name' => 'John Doe',
        'email' => 'john@example.com'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'name' => 'Jane Doe',
        'email' => 'jane@example.com'
    ),
);

foreach ( $array  as $groupid => $fields) {
    echo "hi element ". $groupid . "\n";
    echo ". name is ". $fields['name'] . "\n";
    echo ". email is ". $fields['email'] . "\n";
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
         echo ". field $i is ".$field . "\n";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
hi element 0
. name is John Doe
. email is john@example.com
. field 0 is John Doe
. field 1 is john@example.com
hi element 1
. name is Jane Doe
. email is jane@example.com
. field 0 is Jane Doe
. field 1 is jane@example.com
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware there is no built in php function to do this, you need to do it via a  loop or via a custom method that recursively calls to something like array_fill inidcated in the answer by @Amber;

I'm assuming you mean created an empty but intialized array of arrays.  For example, you want a final results like the below of a *array of 3 arrays*:

```
   $final_array = array(array(), array(), array());
```

This is simple to just hand code, but for an arbitrary sized array like a an *array of 3 arrays of 3 arrays* it starts getting complex to initialize prior to use:

```
     $final_array = array(array(array(), array(), array()), array(array(), array(), array()), array(array(), array(), array()));
```

...etc...

I get the frustration. It would be nice to have an easy way to declare an initialized array of arrays any depth to use without checking or throwing errors.

Answer (score 2):

And for me the argument about whether an array should be sparse or not depends on the context.

For example, if $a[6][9] is not populated is the equivalent to $a[6][9] being populated with for example with "" or 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
$r = array("arr1","arr2");
```

to echo a single array element you should write:

```
echo $r[0];
echo $r[1];
```

output would be: `arr1 arr2`

Comment: This is a one dimensional array. A multidimensional array has at the very least, an array within an array.

Answer (score 1):

And I like this way:

```
$cars = array
  (
  array("Volvo",22),
  array("BMW",15),
  array("Saab",5),
  array("Land Rover",17)
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but second dimension values will be equals to indexes:

`$array = array_fill_keys(range(0,5), range(0,5));`

a little more complicated for empty array:

`$array = array_fill_keys(range(0, 5), array_fill_keys(range(0, 5), null));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare an array in another array.

`$arr = array(array(content), array(content));`

Example:

`$arr = array(array(1,2,3), array(4,5,6));`

To get the first item from the array, you'll use `$arr[0][0]`, that's like the first item from the **first** array from the array.
`$arr[1][0]` will return the first item from the **second** array from the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
//  You can define your 2D array like this ...
$numbers = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];

// ... or for Questions and Answers like this ...
$QaA = [
    ['Question_1', 'Answer_1'],
    ['Question_2', 'Answer_2']    ];

// ... and return some very value like this ...
echo $QaA[1][1];      //  "Answer_2"

//  And you can browse through all this 2D array:
foreach ( $QaA as $nr1 => $content )  {
    echo "\n";
    foreach ($content as $nr2 => $answer) {
        echo "    $nr1, $nr2:  $answer";     }  }

/*  Result:
    0, 0:  Question_1    0, 1:  Answer_1
    1, 0:  Question_2    1, 1:  Answer_2     */

//   Thus you can see all the array:
print_r($QaA);   /*   Result: 
Array  (
    [0] => Array  (
          [0] => Question_1
          [1] => Answer_1  )     
    [1] => Array ( 
          [0] => Question_2
          [1] => Answer_2    )   )   */
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to quickly create multidimensional array for simple value using one liner I would recommend using this [array library](https://github.com/minwork/array) to do it like this:

```php
$array = Arr::setNestedElement([], '1.2.3', 'value');
```

which will produce

```php
[
  1 => [
    2 => [
      3 => 'value'
    ]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score -2):

Very late for the party, but for anyone searching this nowadays - if you want to simply declare a bidimensional array like you would in c# simply declare it in the scope as follows:

```
<?php
  $My2dArray = array(array());
  //This allows you to use it as a bidimensional array. See this loop for example:
  for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $My2dArray[$i]["whatever-you-want"] = "MyValue";
  }
  
  return $My2dArray;
?>
```

Comment: array(array()); is not needed, array(); is enough. static whatever-you-want hardly makes any sense, use a simple 1-d array instead. return hardly makes sense in this context.