# how do I mount this type of array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

how do I mount an array in this format with php?

```
array(6) {
    [0]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> int(10)
        [1]=> string(10) "2014-09-02"
    }
    [1]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> int(11)
        [1]=> string(10) "2014-09-07"
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "mount"?

Comment: Have heard the word in linux ..:o..:p

Comment: Same issue, please see there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811100/how-to-declare-a-two-dimensional-array-most-easily-in-php

Comment: You can define a array but what do you mean by  mount?

Comment: The array only has 2 elements so `array(6)` is fictional?

Comment: @Ja͢ck Ah, but add all the elements and we have 6. It's safe to assume OP wrote this var dump by hand?

Comment: Thats what I assumed. OP seems to be coming from a C/java paradigm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what 'mount' means in the context of php, but if you mean declare and use then you need to understand a few things. This is not idiomatic php. Php does not really have arrays (in the C sense of contiguous memory), there is no need to declare size when setting.

```
$array = array();
$array[] = array();
$array[0][0] = 10;
$array[0][1] = '2014-09-07';
```

etc. They just grow dynamically on the heap.