# How to output a multidimensional array?

Tags: php

I am new to multidimensional array in php, I read this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26348433/1018804) and I tried to create my bidimensional array but how do I output it?

```
$nPost = array("orange, table");
$count_values = array("fruit, forniture");
$final_array = array(array($count_values), array($nPost));
```

Output would have to be:

```
Fruits: orange, Forniture: table
```

Tried

`print_r($final_array)`;

But i got

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => fruit, forniture ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => orange, table ) ) )
0 fruit, forniture
```

**UPDATE**

Real life full code is (explanation in code comments):

```
    <?php
                      $stack = array();
$userID = array();
$nPost = array();


$blogusers = get_users( 'orderby=nicename&role=author' );

foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {

   // get the language list for each user, and push to array

    $descTokens = explode(',', $user->user_description);
    $stack = array_merge($stack, $descTokens);

   // get the ID for each user, and push to the array
   // get the number of posts for each user ID and push to array

    $the_user_id = $user->ID;
    $numPosts = count_user_posts( $the_user_id );
    array_push($userID, $the_user_id);
    array_push($nPost, $numPosts);
 }

   // get the count for each language by counting the duplicate strings

 $count_values = array();
 foreach ($stack as $a) {
   @$count_values[$a]++;
 }
 $total_duplicates = 0;
 foreach ($count_values as $a) {
   if($count_values[$a]<=1){
      unset($count_values[$a]);
   } else{
      $total_duplicates += $count_values[$a];
   }
  }

 for($i = 0; $i < count($count_values); $i++){
   $final_array[$count_values[$i]] = $nPost[$i];
 }

foreach($final_array as $label => $item){
   echo "$label: $item, ";
}
    ?>
          // This gives me a correct result but not the n. posts
    <ul>
      <?php 
          foreach ($count_values as $key=>$count) { 
              echo '<li>'.$key.' '.$count.'</li>'; 
          }
      ?>
     </ul>
```

What we're trying to achieve is:

- 1 French with 2 posts
- 3 English with 5 posts

Comment: [Yo dawg!](https://cdn.meme.am/instances/500x/66975881/yo-dawg-yo-dawg-i-heard-you-liked-arrays-so-we-put-an-array-inside-your-array.jpg) For starters: `$final_array = array($count_values, $nPost);` It's probably still not what you want.

Comment: @mkaatman lol @ the meme. Probably not what I want but it's a try, what's your shot? :D

Comment: Try something like: `$things['fruit'] = 'orange';$things['furniture'] = 'table';print_r($things);`

Comment: you send fruit and orange like one string ("orange, table") with no key and php give the default key which is numeric and started from 0 that's why you get `[0] => fruit, forniture`

Comment: @mkaatman yeah ok, we manually set 1 single value for each, but what if we have a list of strings (which in reality are dynamic) ?

Comment: I guess I'd need to see a more real world representative piece of data you're working with. Are you always going to have an array of keys and an array of values and you want to join them into a single array of key/value pairs?

Comment: @mkaatman updated the question with full code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php 

class User {

    public $id;
    public $numPosts;
    public $languages = array();

    public function __construct($id, $numPosts, $lang = array()){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->numPosts = $numPosts;
        $this->languages = $lang;
    }
}

$users = array();

$john = new User(1, 4, array("English", "French"));
$fred = new User(2, 3, array("English"));
$dave = new User(3, 7, array("German", "French", "Spanish"));

$users[] = $john;
$users[] = $fred;
$users[] = $dave;

$langPostCount = array();
$langUserCount = array(); 

foreach($users as $user){
    foreach($user->languages as $lang){
        $langUserCount[$lang] += 1; // this is what you already have from $count_values
        //$langPostCount[$lang] += $user->numPosts; // can be done here but we'll do another loop
    }
}

/* 
 * the following can be done in the above loop, but you already have that functionality in your code
 * just need to do another loop through your languages, tallying the number of posts in that language
 * keep in mind this is not entirely accurate as your users have multiple languages. they might have
 * one post in english and 4 in french. A better way to do this would be to select the number of posts
 * in each language directly from the posts database.
 */

foreach($langUserCount as $lang => $userCount){
    foreach($users as $user){
        if(in_array($lang, $user->languages)){
            $langPostCount[$lang] += $user->numPosts;
        }
    }
}

echo "<ul>";
foreach($langUserCount as $lang => $userCount){
    echo "<li>$userCount $lang with " . $langPostCount[$lang] . " posts.</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

- 2 English with 7 posts.
- 2 French with 11 posts.
- 1 German with 7 posts.
- 1 Spanish with 7 posts.

As you can see, not entirely accurate. You're better off getting post count by querying your posts dataset than by working from the bottom up.

**Try This**

Adds a new tally to the foreach loop at the top, and changes the ul loop at the end.

```
$postsPerLanguage = array(); // add this

foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {

    $descTokens = explode(',', $user->user_description);
    ...
    $numPosts = count_user_posts( $the_user_id );
    ...
    // add this loop
    foreach($descTokens as $lang){
        $postsPerLanguage[$lang] += $numPosts;  
    }
 }

...

<ul>
    <?php 
        foreach ($count_values as $key=>$count) { 
            echo '<li>'.$key.' '.$count.' with '. $postsPerLanguage[$key] .' posts</li>'; 
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141395/discussion-between-rob-m-and-nospi).

Answer (score 0):

Your output doesn't need multidimensional array you can achieve it like this:

```
$final_array = array('Fruits'=> 'orange', 'Furniture'=> 'table')
```

but for example if you have multiple fruits or furniture you can make something like this:

```
$final_array = array('Fruits'=> array('orange', 'apple'), 'Furniture'=> array('table', 'sofa'))
```

and you can access apple like this:

```
echo $final_array['Fruits'][1];
```

and for `print_r($final_array)` we have this:

```
[Fruits] => (
    [0] => orange,
    [1] => apple
)
[Furniture] => (
    [0] => table,
    [1] => sofa
)
```