# 2D array in PHP /HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to ask how I can declare a 2D array in php or html? I want to put in this 2D array results from mysql query. As I know in php 2D array is an array into an array and this does not really help me

Comment: show a sample of your need  ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1811100/4229270

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare a two dimensional array most easily in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811100/how-to-declare-a-two-dimensional-array-most-easily-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

$var = array("array1","array2");

then for echo value you shoud write

echo $var[0];
echo $var[1];

and output would be: array1 array2

Comment: Maybe you mean $array1,$array2

Answer (score 1):

In `HTML` it is not possible because it is front side markup language and run at various browsers not in server.

In `PHP` you can create **two-dimensional** array.

See e.g.,

```
<?php
    $array_2d = array();
    $array_2d[0][1] = "Hello";
    $array_2d[0][2] = "World";

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array_2d);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => Hello
            [2] => World
        )

)
```