# PHP most efficient way to create an multidimensional array containing the values from list of values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic

## Example

The input is an array of string something like

```
$strs = [
  "some string",
  "another string",
  // ...
];
```

The result should be:

```
$result = [
  [
     "somestring",
     true
  ],
  [
     "another string",
     true
  ]
];
```

The application is to create an array for the data provider to test phone numbers in unit tests.

I can do this very easily in a loop, but I am wondering if there is an array function for it.

My loop solution:

```
$result = [];
foreach($strs as $str) {
    $result[] = [$str, true];
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare a two dimensional array most easily in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811100/how-to-declare-a-two-dimensional-array-most-easily-in-php)

Comment: It is similar, but the answers are static, this one is dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_map()` instead

```
$strs = [
  "some string",
  "another string",
  // ...
];
```

```
$result = array_map(function($val){
    return [$val, true];
}, $strs);
```

Or using combination of [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)

```
$result = array_map(null, $strs, array_fill(0, sizeof($strs), true));
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/nnsRH)

Comment: Nice answer. Though it does not say which is most efficient.

Comment: Efficiency is down to the underlying Php implementation.