# Create Main Array that includes multiple child array

Tags: php

How Can I Create a main array that includes multiple child array And be in the form of Jason and I want to add the child Array  to main array in the  Loop

```
    MainArray=[
    array1=[{fname:asdada,lastname:sdsadasda}];
    array2=[{fname:asdada,lastname:sdsadasda}];
    array3=[{fname:asdada,lastname:sdsadasda}];
    ];

echo MainArray[1]->fname;
```

Please see the following pseudo code below:

[pseudo code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWscR.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome on SO. Here nobody code for you, so you have to code your solution and then, if you get some problems or errors aske here. Please read also [mcve]

Comment: You should probably go work through some beginner’s tutorials that explain such basics.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811100/how-to-declare-a-two-dimensional-array-most-easily-in-php this may help.

Answer (score 0):

You should really look into a basic php tutorial.

This is how you do it.

```
$mainArray = [
  'array1' => ['fname' => 'asdada', 'lastname' => 'sdsadasda'],
  'array2' => ['fname' => 'asdada', 'lastname' => 'sdsadasda'],
  'array3' => ['fname' => 'asdada', 'lastname' => 'sdsadasda']
];
echo $mainArray['array1']['fname'];
```

Or use the long notation if you have an older version of php or want backwards compatibility.

```
$mainArray = array(
  'array1' => array('fname' => 'foo', 'lastname' => 'bar'),
  'array2' => array('fname' => 'lorem', 'lastname' => 'ipsum'),
  'array3' => array('fname' => 'test', 'lastname' => 'example')
);
echo $mainArray['array1']['fname'];
```

### Explanation:

The php [variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) sigil is `$`. This means that in order to access a variable or assign something to a variable, you use `$mainArray`. See more on [variables in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

The [php array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) can be used in two different notations. Either `array(...)` or, from **php 5.4** upwards, `[...]`. Other than the opening and closing parts, they are identical. You don't use `:` or `=` to assign individual values inside an array declaration. For this you use the `=>` operator. Each element in an array is separated by a comma (`,`).

E.g.

```
$mainArray = array(
    'A' => 1,
    'B' => 2
];
```

Arrays in Php can be either associative or numerical. What you probably want is that your outer array is numerical, meaning you can access it using `$mainArray[1]`, and your inner array is associative. For numerical arrays, you don't specify a key yourself, so there is no need for the `=>`.

```
$mainArray = array(
    array(),
    array(),
    array()
);
```

And with associative sub arrays this becomes:

```
$mainArray = array(
    array('firstname' => 'foo', 'lastname' => 'bar'),
    array('firstname' => 'test', 'lastname' => 'example'),
    array('firstname' => 'lorem', 'lastname' => 'ipsum')
);
```

In order to access the `firstname` key of the first child array in this *multilevel* array structure, you do:

```
$mainArray[0]['firstname']
```

E.g. (if you want to echo it to the standard output)

```
echo $mainArray[0]['firstname'];
```

Please note that numerical arrays in php start counting on 0, as in most other programming languages. And please note that the key in the associative array is a string, and as such must be surrounded with either `'` or `"`.

I can recommend you [search for a php beginner's tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+beginner+tutorial) and try to write and execute the examples yourself, to get a better grasp of php. If you need somewhere to run your php examples, I can recommend you try an online php environment such as [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/).

### Update on adding values:

You can add more key=>value pairs to an associative array or add more values to a numerical array afterwards in much the same way as you would access or assign to it.

First, let's add a value to a numerical array. You do this by adding `[]` to the end of your variable when assigning. This means that what you assign will be added as a new numerical value to the end of your array.

```
$numericalArray = array(
    7,
    8,
    6,
    12,
    'B'
);
$numericalArray[] = 'C';
// Results in the array: array(7, 8, 6, 12, 'B', 'C')
```

And in order to add a new `key => value` pair to an associative array, you just add it using the new key, e.g.

```
$assoc = array(
    'firstname' => 'Testy',
    'lastname' => 'McTestface'
);
$assoc['middlename'] => 'Tester';
```

So to add a new fname-lastname pair to the mainArray, you would do:

```
$mainArray = array(
    array('fname' => 'foo', 'lastname' => 'bar'),
    array('fname' => 'test', 'lastname' => 'example'),
    array('fname' => 'lorem', 'lastname' => 'ipsum')
);
$mainArray[] = array('fname' => 'new name', 'lastname' => 'new last name');
```

If you want to do this in a loop, you will use the [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php), [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), [while](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) or [do while](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php) structures.

E.g.

```
$mainArray = array(
    array('fname' => 'foo', 'lastname' => 'bar'),
    array('fname' => 'test', 'lastname' => 'example'),
    array('fname' => 'lorem', 'lastname' => 'ipsum')
);
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; ++$i) {
    $mainArray[] = array('fname' => 'new name ' . $i, 'lastname' => 'new last name ' . $i);
}
echo json_encode($mainArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESPACED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES), PHP_EOL;
// [
//   {'fname': 'foo', 'lastname': 'bar'},
//   {'fname': 'test', 'lastname': 'example'},
//   {'fname': 'lorem', 'lastname': 'ipsum'},
//   {'fname': 'new name 0', 'lastname': 'new last name 0'},
//   {'fname': 'new name 1', 'lastname': 'new last name 1'},
//   {'fname': 'new name 2', 'lastname': 'new last name 2'},
// ]
```

Comment: I want to add the child Array  to main array in the  Loop