# Codeigniter sending data from controller to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to pass data from controller to view in Codeigniter.

`Report.php` (Controller)

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
class Report extends Public_Controller
{
 function __construct()
 {
     parent::__construct();
 }
 function index()
 {$data = array(
            'title' => 'My Title',
            'heading' => 'My Heading',
            'message' => 'My Message'
       );
     $this->load->view("templates/dashboard", $data);
 } 
}
```

`dashboard.php`(View file located in `view/templates`)

```
<div class="row">
  <?php
  echo $title;
  ?>
</div>
```

Those codes have executed an error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: title
Filename: templates/dashboard.php
Line Number: 4
```

I need to load title in the dashboard.php

Comment: Your script should be work, There are nothing to wrong

Comment: can you please post your entire view code? My guess is that somewhere in that view you're doing some kind of unset to that $title. Also, looks like you're extending to public_Controller. To check if that is the problem just extend your class to CI_Controller. If the views start to work normally then its something in your Public_Controller. If so, post that too so we can look at that.

Comment: Okay iI will change that into Cl_controllers and let you know

Comment: I have tried this method but nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried lots of deferent things to fix this. I have no idea why this keeps happening, but finally, I fixed my problem using ajax

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
          url:'<?php echo base_url('admin/report/index'); ?>',
          success:function(data){
            $('#same').html(data);
            },
            error: function(){
             alert('Error');
            }
      });
```

Answer (score -1):

use this syntex to define title and other variables.
thanks

```
$this->data['title'] ='My Title';
$this->data['heading'] ='My Heading';
$this->data['message'] ='My Message';
```

Comment: your example is equivalent to OP's example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1811121/2275490

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried this method but nothing happend

Comment: How is this different from OP?